# Facebook and Google login: Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create app that allows users to signup with facebook and google logins. I am trying to understand how it works with firestore. The email and password signup works great but I dont find many examples for facebook and google for firestore with golang and react.  I found few examples for GCP project. The example talks about webservice flow for authentication with providers like google and facebook. Does this apply for firestore as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Signing in to Firebase is not limited to Cloud Firestore. You use Firebase Authentication to sign the users in from the client, and their profile is then available in Firestore's server-side security rules.

For more on signing the users in, see the [Firebase documentation on Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). It was pages for each supported platform (iOS, Android, Web, etc), and each supported identify provider (email+password, Facebook, Google, etc).